# Protractor doesn't work on MacOS Sierra

Tags: node.js, macos, selenium, protractor, macos-sierra

I've updated the node, npm, webdriver-manager, chromedriver and protractor but the browser crashed when the protractor trying to load it.

Also I've already tried to do part of the solutions from gitHub but nothing was help in this use case.

The errors are below -

**Node console:**

```
Idans-MacBook-Pro:tests idan$ ./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor conf.js
[15:12:39] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[15:12:39] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:13:51] E/launcher - session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"546.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397929 (fb72fb249a903a0b1041ea71eb4c8b3fa0d9be5a),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.0 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.12 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'Idans-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.1.23', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
[15:13:51] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"546.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397929 (fb72fb249a903a0b1041ea71eb4c8b3fa0d9be5a),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.0 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.12 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'Idans-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.1.23', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at WebDriverError (/Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:10)
    at SessionNotCreatedError (/Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:308:10)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:639:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:538:13)
    at /Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:472:11
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
    at /Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2820:25
    at /Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:329:24)
    at Builder.build (/Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:458:24)
    at Hosted.DriverProvider.getNewDriver (/Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:37:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:198:43)
    at /Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:285:30
    at _fulfilled (/Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/Users/idan/automation/tests/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[15:13:51] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
Idans-MacBook-Pro:tests idan$
```

**Webdriver manager console:**

```
15:12:39.496 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chrome, chromeOptions={args=[--no-sandbox, --test-type, --memory-metrics, --console, --crash-on-failure], prefs={download={directory_upgrade=true, default_directory=./Users/idan/automation/tests/downloaded/, prompt_for_download=false}}}}]])
15:12:39.513 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chrome, chromeOptions={args=[--no-sandbox, --test-type, --memory-metrics, --console, --crash-on-failure], prefs={download={directory_upgrade=true, default_directory=./Users/idan/automation/tests/downloaded/, prompt_for_download=false}}}}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.22.397929 (fb72fb249a903a0b1041ea71eb4c8b3fa0d9be5a) on port 38520
Only local connections are allowed.
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
15:12:51.195 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'Idans-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.1.23', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:166)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'Idans-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.1.23', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:97)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"546.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397929 (fb72fb249a903a0b1041ea71eb4c8b3fa0d9be5a),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.0 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.12 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'Idans-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.1.23', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:138)
    ... 14 more
15:13:21.516 WARN - Exception: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"546.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397929 (fb72fb249a903a0b1041ea71eb4c8b3fa0d9be5a),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.0 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.12 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'Idans-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.1.23', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Comment: What version of chrome are you using? Also you should use the latest ChromeDriver. The current one is 2.25. Also, what does your capabilities look like in your protractor config? From the logging statements, it looks like there are a lot of flags. Does the browser work without all these flags?

Comment: Version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit) , Regarding the flags they are all of them are necessary and never did troubles.. thanks @cnishina

Answer (score 0):

Update chromedriver to the latest version (I believe it is in v2.25). 
According to the error, you're using chromedriver 2.22 with google Chrome v54 and they're incompatible.

Comment: I've already updated the chromedriver and replace the exe file by myself and it doesn't help.. :/

Comment: Did you unzip the mac os version and chmod the file so it is an executable?

Answer (score 0):

After updating the chromedriver in manually you should do the steps below as well -

- Change "chromedriver": "2.22", to "chromedriver": "2.24", in node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/config.json
- Change mac32 to mac64 in node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/binaries/chrome_driver.js

Now it works like a charm.